# defineAsyncComponent in Vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have been working with vue3-beta release, I just found out that there is a `defineAsyncComponent` in the new library. I haven't found anything about that on the internet.

Just wanted to know what is its use-case and when to use it. how is it different from the `async setup()` feature. and what would be the performance comparison between two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used to [lazy-load](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) a component (and optionally display a place-holder when loading or failing). It exists in Vue2 already but it's not a specific function. Did you read https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0026-async-component-api.md ?